# iPhone reading file - strange behavior

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

so I've got a file called `answers.txt` which looks like this:

```
1:A
2:B
3:BC
......
```

so a bunch of lines separated by a new line

i use this code to get the lines into a `NSArray`:

```
NSStringEncoding encoding;
NSError* error;
NSString* myString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:filePath usedEncoding:&encoding error:&error];  
NSArray *lines = [myString componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"];
```

The file is written unix style, so the lines are separated by `\n` and not `\r\n`

**Now for the problem:**

*When I build on the simulator*, I get a correct array of lines if I split at `\r\n` and an incorrect array if I split at `\n` (I mean it does split at `\n` but then I split again every line at `:`, the second element has a newline at the end)

*When I build on the device*, it does exactly the opposite (it splits correctly at `\n`, and if I split at `\r\n` I get only one element - probably because there is no `\r` in the file)

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1):

Pretty surprising that simulator and device have different behavior, but you can overcome the problem by using this:

```
[str componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet]];
```

[Here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSCharacterSet_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSCharacterSet) for the Docs.